# Angular2 Unable to access sub array Object from Observable object

Tags: angular, nested

My Object hierarchy looks like this

```
export interface MandatoryTags {
    key: string;
    values: string[];
}

export interface Template {
    templateName: string;
    mTags: MandatoryTags[];

}
```

I am trying to access the array from subinterface. I am getting error Property 'mTags' does not exist on type 'Template'

```
this.templateService.getTemplate(value).subscribe(res=>{

          this.selectedTemplate = res as Template;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedTemplate)); //Works
            console.log(this.selectedTemplate.templateName);    //Works
    //      this.listOptions =  this.selectedTemplate.mTags; --> getting error :Property 'mTags' does not exist on type 'Template'

      }, err=>{
          console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: console.log(this.selectedTemplate.mTags); works?? can you post json of this.selectedTemplate and how you declared listOptions?

Comment: {"_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c29d","templateName":"adfadf","templateDesc":"adfadf","isTemplate":"true","checklistStatus":"open","checklistCurrentSection":"0","__v":0,"mTags":[{"key":"OffshoreDPEs","_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c2a1","values":[{"_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c2a2"}]}],"sections":[{"sectionTitle":"adfadf","sectionDescription":"adfadf","_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c29e","questions":[{"questionTitle":"adfadf","questionType":"Multiple Choice","value":"","_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c29f","options":[{"optionTitle":"adfadf","_id":"5a1061cb25107d323c21c2a0"}]}]}]}

Comment: listOptions = [];

Comment: can you try like this this.templateService.getTemplate(value).map((resp: Response) => resp.json()).subscribe(//your code) ?

Comment: I changed this.selectedTemplate = res as Template; to this.selectedTemplate = res; It worked.